# Youtube iframe does not work in html 5

Tags: html

I added the embed link from youtube. I added into my html, but then it says it can't be found!
What it looks like:
[image: http://imgur.com/2BRHNPq]

html:

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="container">

                <h1>My Content</h1>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VV0K0kL2agk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a scheme relative URI (one that starts with `//`).

You are loading your HTML document using the `file:` scheme but YouTube is only available via `http:` or `https:`.

Put your document on a webserver. Install one on your development machine (either your workstation or a test server, which could be a VM) for doing web development.

Comment: How can I put my document on a webserver?

Comment: That depends on the server. If you install one locally then you just put it in the apropriate directory (and access it via `http://localhost` instead of `file://`).

Comment: A nice one is XAMMP (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). This package installs Apache webserver, MySQL and PHP. With it you can even install CMS locally like Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` or `https://` to your `src`

Comment: This makes the HTML less portable between HTTP and HTTPS versions of a site. Better to do testing with a web server (which also makes it a more realistic test environment for everything else).